# Using public variable in global static variable

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to use a public variable in a global static variable. However, it is giving an error: **Compile Error: Variable does not exist: dist **

Here is the controller code:

```
global with sharing class UserStatsController {


public string regn {get; set;}
public string dist {get; set;}    

public list <SelectOption> getValuesr()
{
    list <selectoption> lsreg = new List<selectoption> ();
    lsreg.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    Set<String> regionSet = new Set<String>();
    for (User_Stats__C Rgn : [SELECT Region__c FROM User_Stats__C where Region__c != null and Region__c != 0 and Region__c != 1 and District__c != null and District__c != '0'])
    {
        String region = string.valueOf(Rgn.Region__c);
        if(!regionSet.contains(region)) lsreg.add(new selectoption(region, region));
        regionSet.add(region);
    }
    return lsreg;
}

public list <SelectOption> getValues()
{
    list <selectoption> ls = new List<selectoption> ();
    ls.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    Set<String> distSet = new Set<String>();
    for (User_Stats__C dist : [SELECT District__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0])
    {
        if(!distSet.contains(dist.District__c)) ls.add(new selectoption(dist.District__c, dist.District__c));
        distSet.add(dist.District__c);
    }
    return ls;
}
@RemoteAction  
global static User_Stats__c[] loadOpps(string dist, string regn) {
        Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;  
    return [SELECT Sales_Rep__c, District__c, Region__c, Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c FROM User_Stats__C where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0 and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0 limit 20];
} 
}
```

Following is the VF page:

```
<apex:page Controller="UserStatsController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:includeScript id="a" value="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />
<apex:sectionHeader title="Goal Revision Dashboard" subtitle="District View"/>
<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:form >
 <apex:outputLabel value="Region" />
    <apex:selectList value="{!regn}" size="1" id="Region">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Valuesr}" />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="districtSelect"/>
    </apex:SelectList>

    <br> </br>
    <apex:outputPanel id="districtSelect">
    <apex:outputLabel value="District"/>
    <apex:selectList value="{!dist}" size="1" id="dist">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Values}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="datarefresh,piegraph,bargraph,Num_OSR,OSR_Rev"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <div id="chartBlock" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);
    function initCharts() {        
      UserStatsController.loadOpps(
             function(result, event){ 
                 var visualization = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));
                 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                 data.addColumn('string', 'Sales_Rep__c');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Rental_Revenue_Actual__c');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Rental_Revenue_Goal__c');   
                 for(var i =0; i<result.length;i++){
                    var r = result[i];
                    data.addRow([r.Sales_Rep__c, r.Rental_Revenue_Actual__c, r.Rental_Revenue_Goal__c]);
                  }
                visualization.draw(data, {legend : {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 10}}, width:window.innerWidth,vAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10}},hAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10},showTextEvery:1,slantedText:false}});
          }, {escape:true});
      }
</script>
</apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:page>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

This is an instance variable, he will not be visible from static methods:

```
public string dist {get; set;}
```

`@RemoteAction` annotated methods are necessarily static, and class properties won't populate from viewstate or accessors in your page. I'd recommend handing it into the remote action invocation:

**Server side change:**

```
@RemoteAction global static User_Stats__c[] loadOpps(String dist) {
    return [
        SELECT
            Sales_Rep__c,
            District__c,
            Region__c,
            Rental_Revenue_Actual__c,
            Rental_Revenue_Goal__c
        FROM User_Stats__C
        WHERE District__c = :dist
        AND Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != null
        AND Rental_Revenue_Actual__c != 0
        AND Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null
        AND Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != 0
        LIMIT 20
    ];
}
```

**Client side change:**

```
//this finds the dropdown by the correct id, eg 'j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:dist'
var dist = document.getElementById('{!$Component.dist}').value;

//and passes it into the @RemoteAction invocation as the first argument
UserStatsController.loadOpps(dist, function() {
...
```

Comment: Thanks @user320. The error is gone. However, the district variable holds value of a selectlist. When I change the values of dist in selectlist, it should refresh the data in above select statemement. However, that is not happening. Any reason why so? Thanks again

Comment: `@RemoteAction` are blind to any and all bound variables on pages, including your list. I think you'll need to update your JavaScript to fish out the value of your selectlist from the DOM and hand it wherever you call `Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction` -

Comment: I am very new to visualforce so I could not understand what you meant by update my JavaScript. If you can give an example, that would be most helpful. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Thanks @Robin - now can you see the two lines to amend in the JavaScript?

Comment: Thank @user320. I made these changes (I added the "var dist=" statement with all the other var statements on the client side that is correct i hope). There is no error, but it is still not fetching the data. and the google chart still remains blank. Any idea why?

Comment: The $Component global is sensitive to position and the VF tag structure. Also 'dist' needs to be assigned just before loadOpps is called, preferably not elsewhere - watch out for those two perhaps? @Robin

Comment: I tried all the position for var statement..including just before the statement where loadOpps is being called. But alas the data is still not refreshing..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `dist` is an instance variable and your method is static. Because there is no instance when the code runs, the variable does not exist.
Simply make `dist` static!

Comment: This will compile, but not sure it'd have the desired effect: how will `dist` get any value ever, if the entry point is a @RemoteAction invocation?